# Ignore aggregating project in maven during sonarqube build

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a maven project with the following structure:

- root
- -aggregating
- --module1
- --module2

After running the goal sonar:sonar I get results on my sonar server, except aggregating is counted towards LoC and other metrics, even though it contains no source.

I tried skipping aggregating using 'sonar.skippedModules', but this also skips the submodules.

Someone also suggested using none in the pom of aggregating, but I don't know any plugin which provides this.

EDIT:
Nevermind this, turns out I'm an idiot.  Files are diplayed more than once, but only counted once.

Comment: please show the user what you have tried for better responses.

Comment: What's the purpose of this "aggregating" module? Simply remove it and put "module1" and "module2" right under "root".

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam: Would that I could. We use this structure to build several subprojects.  It still seems sonar should recognize the same file being counted twice?

Comment: If "aggregating" is a "pom" type project, nothing will be counted twice, it will only act as a aggregator. Do you have screenshots of your issue? I don't really get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something makes me think `sonar.includedModules=root,module1,module2` will work OK.